# Sleep Mode and Ajax Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My webpage has an Ajax file which I use to refresh fields from my embedded webserver.  A recent problem seen, is that if I have the webpage running for a long period of time (say 30min) the computer goes into sleep mode and after bringing it up from sleep mode, there is an error message being displayed?  I am 100% sure it is coming from this Ajax file call and I will place it here to see if someone can pick something up:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function()
{
  setInterval(function()
 {
   $.get("index_phaseII_v02.html",function(data,textStatus, jqXHR)
   {

    //Home tab?
    if ($( "#Main" ).tabs( "option", "active" ) == '0')
     {//open tab home

       //Home Sales
       var name1=$('#variable00',data).text();

      //Home
      $('td#variable00').text(name1);



    } //close Home tab



 })
.fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,errorThrown) //Callback failed
   {
    alert("Errors:" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
   })
  .done(function() //Callback succeeded
   {
    $('#errors').text('Errors:');
   })
   },3000);

  });
```

The error it displays is: Errors: error   <------- This is why I know it coming from here by the way!

What is really concerning is that error doesn't tell me much about the error and why this is happening?

By the way, I didn't go thru all my cases above or all the variables, I just displayed the code that is the meat and potatoes of the actual Ajax file (relevant).

I tested disabling the sleep mode on the laptop and the error is not popped up.

Comment: What do you see in the console and the network tab?

Comment: I'd expect you to see an aborted request in the log.

Comment: certainly...it's coming from the alert you have in ajax fail callback. Likely not able to connect in sleep mode, so fail fires